# How to have second dropdown menu values be dependent on value of first dropdown menu in React render function

Tags: reactjs

In the render function of a React component, I have the following code

```
            <select name="env" id="env">
              <option value="Dev">Dev</option>
              <option value="Staging">Staging</option>
              <option value="Prod">Prod</option>
            </select>
           

            <select name="region" id="region">
              <option value="option1">op1</option>
              <option value="option2">op2</option>
              <option value="option3">op3</option>
              <option value="option4">op4</option>
            </select>
```

If Dev option is selected in first dropdown, there should only be op1 choice available in the 2nd dropdown. Similarly if Staging is selected, then op1, op2 and op3 are the available choices. If Prod is selected, then all 4 choices are available. How can I achieve this in React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should render different region options by env.

```js
const regionsByEnv = {
  Dev: ["option1"],
  Staging: ["option1", "option2", "option3"],
  Prod: ["option1, option2, option3, option4"],
};

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [env, setEnv] = useState("");

  const regionOptions = useMemo(() => {
    if (!env) {
      return regionsByEnv.Prod.map((option) => (
        <option value={option} key={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      ));
    }
    return regionsByEnv[env].map((option) => (
      <option value={option} key={option}>
        {option}
      </option>
    ));
  }, [env]);

  return (
    <>
      <select
        value={env}
        onChange={(e) => setEnv(e.target.value)}
        name="env"
        id="env"
      >
        <option value="Dev">Dev</option>
        <option value="Staging">Staging</option>
        <option value="Prod">Prod</option>
      </select>
      <select name="region" id="region">
        {regionOptions}
      </select>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should filter option for select region base on selected option of select env. So you can create a state for handling value of select env

```
export default function App() {
  const [select1, setSelect1] = useState("Dev");
  const filterOption2 = allOption2.filter((i) => {
    return (
      (select1 === "Dev" && i.value === "option1") ||
      (select1 === "Staging" && i.value !== "option4") ||
      select1 === "Prod"
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select name="env" id="env" onChange={(e) => setSelect1(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="Dev">Dev</option>
        <option value="Staging">Staging</option>
        <option value="Prod">Prod</option>
      </select>
      <select name="region" id="region">
        {filterOption2.map((op) => (
          <option key={select1 + op.value} value={op.value}>
            {op.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

const allOption2 = [
  {
    name: "op1",
    value: "option1"
  },
  {
    name: "op2",
    value: "option2"
  },
  {
    name: "op3",
    value: "option3"
  },
  {
    name: "op4",
    value: "option4"
  }
];
```

You can check in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-frost-qmrwmw?file=/src/App.js:58-1135)